# Android canvas animation stuck frame

Tags: android, css, animation, canvas, webkit

I'm having an issue running a canvas animation on Android (4.1.1), spcifically on an Asus Transformer Pad.

Animations run however there seems to be the first frame of the animation stuck behind the running animation.

Has anyone ever came across this issue before or provide some insight into it? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In some versions of android 4.1.1, default browser (AppleWebKit/534.30), the clearRect is broken and you must clear the canvas by setting `canvas.width = canvas.width`.

That's *probably* the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Martin. This reads like a problem I had building a frame-by-frame animation. The canvas never seemed to clear between calls to draw new frames. The result was that images appeared drawn over one another and the animation was a mess.

The following line:

```
canvas.drawColor(color.black, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

cleared the canvas of the previous image before drawing the new one. I positioned this line just before my call to "canvas.drawBitmap()".

Perhaps this will work for you.